# Attaching 'onclick' event to SVG element 'rect' after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm loading different SVG's on a DIV and it works fine, but the onclick bindings are not working.

After loading, I call the LoadSVGBindings function to set the onclick bindings.

The only way it works is by debugging on FireFox.
After stopping at the LoadSVGBindings function then resuming it all works fine.

```
//HTML code
<div id="TheSVG"></div>


//LoadSVG function
function LoadSVG(Mode){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data/' + Mode + '.svg',
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "charset=UTF-8",
        success: function(data) { $('#TheSVG').html(data); },
        error: function(request, status, error) {alert("Error: " + error);},
     });

    SetSVGBindings();
}


//Set after loading the SVG
function SetSVGBindings(){

    $('polygon').on('click', function () {
        alert("polygon");
    });

    $('rect').on('click', function () {
        alert("rect");
    });
}
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong or how to make it work correctly.

Comment: I can not believe it!

Comment: It works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call SetSVGBindings in the success function, i.e. after the SVG has loaded.

The way you've written it in the question SetSVGBindings will be called before the SVG has loaded and there won't be any SVG elements in the document for the CSS selector to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mi function now

```
    function LoadSVG(Modo){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Apoyos/bootstrap/data/' + Modo + '.svg',
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "charset=UTF-8",
            success: function(data) { $('#SVG').html(data); SetSVGBindings();},
            error: function(request, status, error) {alert("Error: " + error);},
         });
    }
```

I don't understand exactly why it did not work before, after all it was loading after the function finished with success.

Many thanks

Comment: `after all it was loading after the function finished with success`, **no it was not**.  `$.ajax` is *asynchronous*, it does not block, the script continues on and `SetSVGBindings` gets called before `$.ajax` has finished.